# How do I use print in Atom with love2d

Tags: atom-editor, love2d

I'm a newbie to love and i'm using Love 11.3 and Sheepolution guide to learning love. In one of their chapters they say

> We can use print to make the number appear in our output console.
> print(3 + 4). --Output: 7. Run your code (meaning press F6 and then
> close the window to show the output) and your console should say 7

My code:

```
function love.draw()
  love.graphics.print("Hello world!", 100,100)
end

print(3+4)
```

When I run this code, a black screen with "Hello world" comes up but nothing says "7". Even in ATOM, down below has a section "Atom-console" but nothing prints there. Is there something I didn't do in my setup that causes the regular print function not to print?

Comment: There was a question just like this last week, but I think it was for another editor, experiencing the same flaw;  that the print() output wasn't being captured.  I was almost certain Atom did, have used it in the past, and would expect it to.  I'm on gEdit at the moment, it does.  I know there are a few Lua plugins for Atom, such as linting and whatnot.  Glance around and see if one adds that functionality to it.  Otherwise, you'll have to open an actual terminal, and run your script from there.

Answer (score 0):

Love2D captures the console output by default. You need to create a new file, `conf.lua` in the same folder as `main.lua`. Your file structure should look like:

```
MyProject.love
 |- main.lua
 |- conf.lua
```

In `conf.lua` we have to turn on the Love2D console with the following:

```
function love.conf(t)
    t.console = true
end
```